Pirate movie with a female lead who eats an octopus
I'm looking for a pirate movie with a female protagonist. I thought it was Pirates of the caribbean II, but after checking it is not. In the film, the female protagonist is pranked by the crew to eat raw octopus tentacles (or something similar) and it messes with her head.
Other things that might be true: 

I thought it was from Pirates of the Caribbean II.   
I think she might have been imprisoned on the ship, demands food, and someone gives her an octopus to eat. Her friends tell her not to, but she doesn't care, she is too hungry.   
Later, she is permitted to walk freely on the ship. People snigger around her, and she is recommending the "wonderful" octopus to everyone. Then a friend weans her off it, and she gets her sense back and is again disgusted by octopus.

I saw this film somewhere between 2000-2010, but the movie could easily have been from the 90s or earlier.
I would assume the movie is in English, but it is too long ago for me to accurately remember whether I saw it with subtitles or not.
Other movies I thought it might've been are Roman Polanski's Pirates or Cutthroat Island, but I can't find the scenes - possibly it is part of some extended/director's cut.

The Pirate movie is my guess. http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0084504/

Any chance it's Pirates or Pirates 2? The porn movies that were such big blockbuster budgets and reception that they were edited to be Rated R movies as well? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pirates_(2005_film)

@joshbot it is not "The Pirate Movie" unofortunately, but I'm very glad you suggested it all the same. Because that is one pirate movie I have yet to see :D Bonus!

@cde As far as I can tell at 3x viewing speed, the only eaten tentacles in those movies are the ones, one might expect from movies of that genre. I couldn't spot any octopus-attached tentacles. Thanks for the suggestion though :)

3x viewing speed, eh? :p

I'm not sure how old the female antagonist in the film you're looking for is suppose to be, but I did find a TV-Movie called Pirate's Island made in 1995 about a group of kids, lead by a female protagonists, whose hot air balloon crashes on a Pirate-infested Island. It's kind of like Swiss Family Robinson/PeterPan mash-up. I have not found a scene though where she eats something like Octopus or Squid...
